# Pyspark SaveAsTextFile() & textFile() not recognizing list format of RDD elements

Tags: pyspark, text-files

I have a rdd whose elements are lists of the following format `(('string', 'string'), int)` :

```
print(my_rdd.take(1))
Out >> [((u'string_1', u'string_2'), 1)]
```

However after I a write / read, each element is seen as a string :

```
my_rdd.saveAsTextFile('my_path')
read_rdd = sc.textFile('my_path')

print(read_rdd.take(1))

Out >> [u"((u'string_1', u'string_2'), 1)"]
```

What is the best practice ? Do I need to improve my write operation or my read operation ?

Comment: any reason why you work with rdd and not dataframe ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, any kind of long-term storage takes a string or a binary string, so this conversion to a unicode string seems normal. Just write a function to parse it back into the format you need.